# How to test the OPTIONS HTTP request in Robot Framework?

Tags: httprequest, robotframework

I am using a library called *HttpLibrary* to assert the status of my requests, among which a OPTIONS one. I read on the following article that this library has been fixed to enable the OPTIONS requests, I upgraded the library using a console command, but it still doesn't recognise OPTIONS as a keyword.
Do you know what am I doing wrong? See the link below where they talk about this fix:

https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary/issues/30

How do I get it to work? Is there another way to update a Library version? Do I have to update RIDE too?

Comment: What is your lib version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the link you've provided the pull request with `OPTIONS` keyword isn't merged yet. Consider to use `Http Request` with `verb` set as `OPTIONS`.

Comment: That explains a lot,thank you. I have tried to use that library but I can't make it work either because the examples provided aren't very descriptive for my level of knowledge. Thank you for your help